# Vuetify - How to nest v-menu, v-badge and v-btn correctly

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm creating a Vue/ Nuxt application, and am working on a user notifications feature for the Navbar. The notification is an icon, and if the user has notifications, there should be a v-badge as a little red dot. On click of this icon, a menu should drop down to show the user's notifications. I've been reading the Vuetify menu docs, and specifically this section that talks about [nested activators](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/#misc).

Currently the icon doesn't show and there's no way to activate the menu, however the v-badge does show. It did display correctly before adding the v-menu and nested activators.

Here is my current code:

```js
      <v-menu>
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on: menu, attrs }">

          <v-badge
            class="notification-badge"
            color="secondary"
            :content="currentUser.notifications.length || 0"
            dot
            :value="currentUser.notifications.length || 0">

            <template v-slot:activator="{ on: badge }">
              <v-btn
                v-bind="attrs"
                color="primary"
                depressed
                icon
                v-on="{ ...badge, ...menu }">
                <custom-icon
                  color="#4a4a4a"
                  height="20px"
                  name="bell"
                  width="20px" />p
              </v-btn>
            </template>

          </v-badge>
        </template>

        <v-list
          dense
          elevation="1">
          <v-list-item-group>
            <v-list-item
              v-for="item in currentUser.notifications"
              :key="item.id"
              two-line>
              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>{{ item.message }}</v-list-item-title>
                <v-list-item-subtitle>{{ formatDate(item) }}</v-list-item-subtitle>
              </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list-item-group>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
```

And just to give an idea of what this icon/feature looks like:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Solved it in a slightly different way by going the [Absolutely Without Activator](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/#slots) route.

```
    <template>
      <v-badge
        bottom
        class="notification-badge"
        color="secondary"
        :content="currentUser.notifications.length || 0"
        dot
        left
        overlap
        :value="currentUser.notifications.length || 0">
        <v-btn
          depressed
          icon
          :ripple="false"
          @click="openNotificationsMenu">
          <custom-icon
            color="#4a4a4a"
            height="20px"
            name="bell"
            width="20px" />
        </v-btn>
      </v-badge>

      <v-menu
        v-model="showMenu"
        absolute
        offset-y
        :position-x="menuPosition.x"
        :position-y="menuPosition.y"
        style="max-width: 400px">
        <v-list
          dense
          elevation="1">
          <v-list-item-group>
            <v-list-item
              v-for="item in currentUser.notifications"
              :key="item.id"
              two-line>
              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title>{{ item.message }}</v-list-item-title>
                <v-list-item-subtitle>{{ formatDate(item) }}</v-list-item-subtitle>
              </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list-item-group>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
    </template>

    <script>
      export default {
        data: () => ({
          showMenu: false,
          menuPosition: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
          }
        }),

        methods: {
          openNotificationsMenu (e) {
            this.showMenu = true;
            this.menuPosition.x = e.clientX;
            if (e.clientY < 60) {
              this.menuPosition.y = 60;
            } else {
              this.menuPosition.y = e.clientY;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
```